# Suppress "warning: ISO C++11 does not support" when using strftime()

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, suppress-warnings, strftime

So I am currently using strftime() to format a tm object in a given format. I'm trying to use

```
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%a %d %b %04Y", &timeinfo);
```

but this is not available in C++11 which isn't a problem because I'm trying to use C++17 but when I compile using

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -Wfatal-errors -c main.cc
```

I get this error because of -Werror

```
main.cc: In function ‘void print_date(int, int, int, int)’:
main.cc:118:38: error: ISO C++11 does not support the '0' strftime flag [-Werror=format=]
     strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%a %d %b %04Y", &timeinfo);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

so when I remove -Werror I get this warning

```
main.cc: In function ‘void print_date(int, int, int, int)’:
main.cc:118:38: warning: ISO C++11 does not support the '0' strftime flag [-Wformat=]
     strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%a %d %b %04Y", &timeinfo);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cc:118:38: warning: ISO C++11 does not support field width in strftime format [-Wformat=]
```

but is there a way to suppress this warning? I honestly don't even understand why I'm getting this error if I'm compiling main.cc with -std=c++17.

is it something to do with my g++ version when I do g++ --version it outputs

```
g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-16)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `%04Y`? `%Y` implies 4 digits. *`%Y`     The year as a decimal number including the century.*

Comment: *"I honestly don't even understand why I'm getting this error if I'm compiling main.cc with -std=c++17"* -- Suppression should be reserved for the situations where you understand why you are getting the warning (treated as an error) and can determine that the warning is not a sign of trouble. Better would be to ask why you are getting this warning/error.

Comment: You should read that as "C++11 and later". (I don't think anyone has had the time, or urge, to go through all messages and adjust them to mention the standard that's in effect.)

Comment: I'm not using just %Y because when I use that it only returns as many digits are in the year, so year = 1 would by '1' but I want it to be '0001'

Comment: @KevinTruong *"so year = 1 would by '1' but I want it to be '0001'"* -- this would be useful information if it was edited into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The warning "warning: ISO C++11 does not support field width in strftime format" is the key thing here. `%04Y` is nonsensical. Just use `%Y`, which *already* means "use the complete year" (`%y` is the two-digit truncated form). [`strftime` isn't `printf`, it has its own formatting language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime), and `%04Y`is not something it understands.

Yes, technically, this means dates before the year 1000 will be less than four digits. If you need to handle them, and have them be zero padded out to four digits, you're going to have to mix `strftime` and regular string formatting, or use [an appropriate `std::formatter` from C++20's `std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock/formatter) (where `%Y` is explicitly documented to zero pad out to four digits if needed).